# How to refer to any type from all types used in an interface?

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```
interface IElementWithAttrs {
  someAttrA: X
  someAttrB: Y
  someAttrC: Z
}

const getModifiedElement = (element: IElementWithAttrs, attr: keyof IElementWithAttrs, value: X | Y | Z): IElementWithAttrs => {
  return {...element, [attr]: value}
}
```

How can I change `X | Y | Z` as `value`'s type in the function signature for something more generic that refers to any type being used in my interface? My guess `typeof keyof IElementWithAttrs` doesn't seem to be valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface IElementWithAttrs {
    someAttrA: string
    someAttrB: number
    someAttrC: boolean
}

const modifyElement = <K extends keyof IElementWithAttrs>(
    element: IElementWithAttrs,
    attr: K,
    value: IElementWithAttrs[K]
): IElementWithAttrs => {
    return { ...element, [attr]: value }
}

modifyElement(null, 'someAttrA', 1); // Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Comment: No problem, Always remember to use type variables `<K extends Type>` in such cases.

Comment: @JordiNebot Might want to spread the element before you make the modification to avoid keeping the old attribute

Comment: Good catch @AsafAviv! Anyway this is just some sample code I made up for the question, not my real use case.